# ffmpeg says "at least one output file must be specified" when piping from another process

Tags: ffmpeg

To force ffmpeg to read, decode, and scale only once in order to bring CPU usage down I put those steps in one ffmpeg process and piped the result into another ffmpeg process that performed the encoding.

This improved the overall processing time by 15–20%.

```
INPUT_STREAM="ffmpeg -i $INPUT_FILE -vf scale=720:-1,crop=720:400 -threads auto -f yuv4mpegpipe -"

$INPUT_STREAM | ffmpeg -y -f yuv4mpegpipe -i - \
$AUDIO_OPTIONS_P2 $VIDEO_OPTIONS_P2 -b:v 250k -threads auto out-250.mp4 \
$AUDIO_OPTIONS_P2 $VIDEO_OPTIONS_P2 -b:v 500k -threads auto out-500.mp4 \
$AUDIO_OPTIONS_P2 $VIDEO_OPTIONS_P2 -b:v 700k -threads auto out-700.mp4
```

I then tried the syntax below:

```
 ffmpeg -i c:\sample.mp4 -threads auto -f yuv4mpegpipe - |  ffmpeg -y -f yuv4mpegpipe -i -vcodec libx264 -b:v 250k -threads auto c:\out-250.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 260k -threads auto c:\out-260.mp4
```

… but this error appears:

> At least one output file must be specified

But I have specified the out put file which is: `C:\out-260.mp4`. Still it doesn't work

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ffmpeg -y -f yuv4mpegpipe -i -vcodec …
```

You didn't specify any input file. To read from stdin, use `-`:

```
ffmpeg -y -f yuv4mpegpipe -i - -vcodec …
```

Comment: @M.Yazdian You can also use `-i pipe:`. See [pipe protocol documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) for more details.